# Gridstack.JS - Cannot get the 'drag and drop' example working in Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, gridstack

I was able to get the 'trash' part working via code but for whatever reason I cannot figure out how to get the 'Drag and drop'/'Drag and Create' portion working like the Advanced example shows on the website.

https://gridstackjs.com/demo/web2.html

I have searched the documentation and simply cannot figure out how they've made it work.

Can anyone familiar with Gridstack.JS show me an example in angular of how to implement the Drag and Drop/Drag and Create feature like they have in the example above?